# Issue with using Office Interop with Excel and .NET 4.0/4.5

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I have the following bit of code that works fine when I target .NET 3.5:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application _excelInstance;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet _excelWorksheet;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook _excelWorkbook;

_excelInstance = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
_excelWorkbook = _excelInstance.Workbooks.Add();
_excelWorksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)_excelWorkbook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
```

However, when I target .NET 4.5, the compiler gives the following error for the last line above:

> One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?

I am unable to target .NET 3.5 for this project, it must be 4.0 or 4.5.

Any idea what would be causing this, or how I should go about fixing this?

Thanks.

edit -

Here is the entier class:

```
public class ExcelWriter : IDisposable
{
    private string _outputFile;

    public ExcelWriter(string outputFile)
    {
        _outputFile = outputFile;
    }

    public void Write(List<string[]> data)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application _excelInstance;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet _excelWorksheet;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook _excelWorkbook;

        _excelInstance = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        _excelWorkbook = _excelInstance.Workbooks.Add();
        _excelWorksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)_excelWorkbook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        int rowNumber = 1;

        foreach (var row in data)
        {
            int columnNumber = 1;

            foreach (var field in row)
            {
                _excelWorksheet.Cells[rowNumber, columnNumber] = field;
                columnNumber++;
            }

            rowNumber++;
        }

        if (File.Exists(_outputFile))
        {
            File.Delete(_outputFile);
        }

        _excelWorkbook.SaveAs(_outputFile);
        _excelWorkbook.Close();
        _excelInstance.Quit();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (File.Exists(_outputFile))
        {
            File.Delete(_outputFile);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of office? I tried the exact same with 14.0 and got no compiler error in framework 4.5

Comment: I'm using Office 2010.

Comment: So it works for me. There must be something you are leaving out here. Please include more detail (project type, other code you didnt show, etc). I assume VS2012?

Comment: Correct, VS 2012. Not sure what else to include other than the entire class file. I can do that, though.

Comment: What does your app.config file look like?

Comment: Have you tried this instead? "_excelWorksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)_excelWorkbook.Worksheets(1);"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, the Excel type library will be translated differently when you add a reference to the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel interop assembly when you target .NET 4.0 and up.  It will take advantage of the added *dynamic* keyword.  Lots of use for this in Office interop, it is an object model that returns "variants" in many places.  Previously they were translated to *object*, now to *dynamic*.

Which requires a framework assembly that's not part of your project.  Probably because you converted it from a previous VS version.

Right-click the References node of your project, Add Reference, select Microsoft.CSharp.